# read plist from documents

Tags: load, plist, documents

I have a plist on my server for populating my map with annotations information.
When i read it from the server everything working & a copy of the plist file is created to the documents path.
I'm trying to read my plist in the documents path when there is no internet connection but it doesn't work.
If i'm writing in my code to go to the bundle when there is no internet - its working but from documents - no.
(i have changed just for the question the path of the plist file in my dropbox)
What's wrong in my code?
Thanks for your help in advanced!

```
- (void) showMap 
{
storsInfosArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:
                 [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4082823/AppsFiles/test.plist"]];

NSString *error;
NSString *rootPath =
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];
NSArray *tmpArr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:storsInfosArr];
NSData *tmpData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:tmpArr format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

if(tmpData)
{
    [tmpData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}

else 

{
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}

//Check if the array loaded from server is not complete, load from docs:
if(tmpArr.count == 0)
{
    NSString *rootPath =
    [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stores.plist"];

    NSLog(@"docsPlistPath = %@",plistPath);

    // Build the array from the plist  
    NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    self.storsInfosArr = tmpArray;
}

for (NSDictionary *currStoreDict in storsInfosArr)
{
    StoreAnnotation *stAnnotation = [[StoreAnnotation alloc] initWithDictionary:currStoreDict];
    [myMapView addAnnotation:stAnnotation];
}

myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

CLLocationCoordinate2D tmpCoord2d = {31.48489338689016, 35.5517578125};
MKUserLocation *userLocation = myMapView.userLocation;
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.location.coordinate,390000.0, 390000.0);
[myMapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
myMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
self.myMapView.centerCoordinate = tmpCoord2d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi following code will help you in reading plist from `NSDocumentDirectory`:

```
if(netConnection==0)
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    if (!documentsDirectory) {
        NSLog(@"Documents directory not found!");
    }

    NSArray *myWords = [@"Data.plist" componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/"]];
    NSString *PlistFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[myWords lastObject]];

    NSLog(@"%@",PlistFilePath);

    NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:PlistFilePath];

    //Load Plist root element into Dictionary object Fist

    self.dataDict = tempDict;

    [tempDict release];

    //From DataDict retrieve the Array 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. but it gives me an error on self.dataDictonary = tempDict; what is the dataDictionary? i don't have dictionary variable if that what u ment..

Comment: dataDicitionary is variable used to access the Root element of plist . Root element allows to  access the remaining values inside plist.

Answer (score -1):

Root element of plist needs to be Loaded in Dictionary Variable before Accessing the Other Objects.

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
  <key>Levels</key> //this is Root Element

  <array>
  <dict>
 <key>Title</key><string>Screen Based Videos</string>
  </dict>

  <dict>
  <key>Title</key><string>Action Based Videos</string>
  </dict>

   </array>
   </dict>
   </plist>
```

First Create a Dictionary Variable in App Delegate Class.

```
 .h AppDelClass

NSDictionary *DataDict;

@property(nonatomic,retain)  NSDictionary *DataDict;



.M AppDelClass

@sythesize DataDict;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{

Check Network Connection using Rechability Class form Apple Doc

NSURL *XmlDataURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/ideploy/testing/Data.plist"];


if(NetConnection==YES)
{


   theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:XmlDataURL    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    Connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self  startImmediately:YES];

}

else
{


   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    if (!documentsDirectory){
        NSLog(@"Documents directory not found!");
    }
    NSArray *myWords = [@"Data.plist" componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/"`]];
NSString *PlistFilePath = `[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[myWords lastObject]];

NSLog(@"%@",PlistFilePath);

NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:PlistFilePath];

//Load Plist root element into Dictionary object Fist

 self.dataDict = tempDict;

[tempDict release];

}

//Root Class Implementation
 .h file

NSArray *tableDataSource;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tableDataSource;

.M file

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

     NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    self.tableDataSource = tempArray;
   [tempArray release];

 RootClassAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (RootClassAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication  sharedApplication] delegate];

 self.tableDataSource = [AppDelegate.data objectForKey:@"Levels"];

     NSLog(@"%i",[tableDataSource count]);

// form the tableDataSource Array you can Access remaining elemements


}
```

Comment: I have had a look at some of your answers and you need to make sure your answers are formatted correctly. Like this answer needs sorting. Why have you got things like '<br>' these are not needed. When adding code you only need to do 4 spaces. And because of this your answer looks puzzling, so -1.